# moveToThread doesn't seem to work (PyQt, class composition)

Tags: python, pyqt, qthread

I have the following setup (simplified):

```
class A(object):

    def foo(self):


class B(QObject, A):

    QObject.__init__(self)
    A.__init__(self)

...

thread = QThread()
b = B()
b.moveToThread(thread)
thread.start()
```

---

`foo` is invoked via a signal, but executes in the main thread.

I understand moveToThread doesn't work for objects with parents, but that doesn't seem relevant.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @ekhumoro, http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#moveToThread

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the slot being run in the wrong thread. Threading issues are usually extremely subtle and simplified examples generally remove or obscure the cause of the problem.